# Laravel Eloquent where with calculation on value

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a column in my table called `date` which is of type `TIMESTAMP`.

I am trying to add a very simply scope which will return all results that have a date of tomorrow.

I think I want to be able to do something like this:

```
public function scopeTomorrow($query)
{
    return $query->where('date', function ($date) {
        return \Carbon\Carbon::parse($date)->isTomorrow();
    });
}
```

But the `$date` variable is currently just the query builder.

How can I create a `where` statement which accepts the value and perfroms some sort of check on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
return $query->where('date', '>=', Carbon::tomorrow())
             ->where('date', '<=', Carbon::tomorrow()->endOfDay());
```

Or:

```
return $query->whereBetween('date', [Carbon::tomorrow(), Carbon::tomorrow()->endOfDay()]);
```

Also, probably you want to add `date` to `$dates` variable.

Comment: Thanks @Alexey. For the future does this mean there is no way to actually accept the value?

Comment: I don't thinks it's possible to use something like `isTomorrow()` here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
public function scopeTomorrow($query)
{
    $tomorrow = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->addDay(1);

    return $query->where('date', '=', $tomorrow);
}
```